# azure-devops-migration-tools and having difficulty validating results and it is not updating previously migrated Test Configurations

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I am using azure-devops-migration-tools to migrate from TFS 2017 to Azure Devops SERVER 2022. I have some questions.

1. Validation - Not all Test plans are migrated. Trying to come up with a way of quickly verifying all the Test Plans and Test Suite have been migrated. A Query in the source shows more test plans / suites than in the destination. However, the number of test plans / suites visible in the "Tests" app of TFS does appear to match. Can't really tell with Test suites because there are so many. Since there is limited to no filtering capabilities I am wondering which Test Plans / Suites get skipped and if there is a way to identify them in the source before the migration.
2. We ran into an issue in one migration where test suites were not completely migrated because of being associated with test cases which had INACTIVE test configurations.  We made all the test configurations ACTIVE on the source in hopes of getting a complete migration, but the test configurations were not updated and remained INACTIVE on the target.  Do Test Plans, Suites, Configurations get updated like work items do?

Just trying to come up with a best practice for Test "objects" so I can validate what was migrated.

Also an understanding of what will definitely not be migrated because it is not possible.  This is so I can set Product Team expectations and be able to quantitatively analyze the results and be confident I migrated all that is possible to migrate.